# Spring Integration retry advice configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to configure a retryadvice.

is this will work?

`IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")`

`.transform(theTranformer , "theTransfomerMethod" , e -> e.handleMessageAdvice(new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice()))`

`.channel("outputChannel").get();`

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but only with a remark made on JavaDocs of that `handleMessageAdvice`:

```
/**
 * Configure a list of {@link MethodInterceptor} objects to be applied, in nested order, to the
 * endpoint's handler. The advice objects are applied to the {@code handleMessage()} method
 * and therefore to the whole sub-flow afterwards.
 * @param interceptors the advice chain.
 * @return the endpoint spec.
 * @since 5.3
 */
public S handleMessageAdvice(MethodInterceptor... interceptors) {
```

If you want to retry only your `theTransfomerMethod` then consider to configure this advice via:

```
/**
 * Configure a list of {@link Advice} objects to be applied, in nested order, to the
 * endpoint's handler. The advice objects are applied only to the handler.
 * @param advice the advice chain.
 * @return the endpoint spec.
 */
public S advice(Advice... advice) {
```

Comment: I am having no problem at all , i was flusing an index on elastic  (i have an integration flow to index some docs) and some fails appeared on log then,  i wondered if i could use a retry strategy using this configuration on transformer.

Comment: but thinking better it will not work need to perform a complete check on documents sent at end of integration, i guess spring-data-elastic does not throw an exception if the http method fails.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with `spring-data-elastic`. Perhaps, if you share some simple project to play with, then I'd debug it to see what is going.